# ¿Es posible llamar un constructor desde otro? C#

Tags: c#, constructor

Buen día!

En caso de tener dos constructores, por ejemplo..

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(object o)
    {
        if(/* blah.. condición */)
            //continuar en el otro constructor
    }
    public Test()
    {
        /*Configuraría ciertos parámetros en caso de que 
        el parámetrod e la función anterior fuese válido.
         */        
    }
}
```

Sería posible, desde el primer constructor, `Test(object o)`, basado en cierta condición, continuar en el constructor `Test()`?

Sé que lo más coherente sería desacoplar el código de `Test()` a una función y llamarla de ambos constructores en caso de ser necesario.

Pero se dió el caso  y me surgió la duda, ¿Es posible?

Comment: Basado en cierta condición, por defecto no. Si que podrías llamar siempre a un constructor desde otro, usando `:this()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede llamar un constructor basado en una condicion debido se violaria la regla de que el primero en ejecutarse es el constructor.

Veo 2 formas en como puedes lograr lo que quieres.

1- Pasas una expresion boolan al constructor desde el segundo utilizando `this` y asi decides si ejecutar o no el codigo en el primero:

```
public Test(object o) : this(o == null)
{
    if(/* blah.. condición */)
        //...
}
public Test(bool noEsNull = false)
{
   if(noEsNull)
   {
        // ...
   }
}
```

2- Pones el codigo del primer constructor en  un metodo y asi haces la condicion en el segundo:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(object o)
    {
        if(/* blah.. condición */)
            metodoConstructor1();
    }
    public Test()
    {
       metodoConstructor1();
    }

    private void metodoConstructor1()
    {
            // codigo constructor 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Gran explicación, muchas por tomarte el tiempo!